# Obfs4 bridges in Orbot

Tags: bridge, orbot, obfs4

I can connect to obfs3 bridges just fine and even meek works, but obfs4 bridges seem to immediately reject my client. The debug log output is of no help. It's almost like Orbot isn't sending the bridge's public key properly or something. Has anyone gotten this to work?

Comment: "only ARM chips can support the new Obfs4, Meek bridges". from v15 RC3 release announcement.

Comment: if Tor logs show "can't parse bridge line", check the format of obfs4 bridge in orbot setting: "+" in the cert part might be missing.

Comment: Considering most Android devices are ARM-based, I don't see how that's a problem. I know my 2013 Moto X certainly is. I am also NOT getting the "can't parse bridge line" error. I used to get that when copying the bridge string from email and it would omit a space right after the IP address. It just rejects silently after acknowledging the correct bridge line. Oh yeah, and scramblesuit also fails due to another, unrelated issue of not including the PT proxy in the build.

Comment: It would be helpful if you paste your log here.  Any warning messages? obfs4 and meek work on nexus 7 with cm12.  I'm not sure the new release supports scramblesuit bridges.